# Roblox - invalid argument #2 to 'remove' (number expected, got string)

Tags: lua, roblox

so I have a simple problem that can probably be easily fixed. My script randomly chooses a string from a table. After it has chosen it ad displayed it, it removes it from the table. But when I try to do that, I get this error, invalid argument #2 to 'remove' (number expected, got string). Here is my script.

```
local textTable = {
    "What is this?",
    "What is that?",
    "What would match this statement?",
    "Pick the option that would match the image."
}

while wait(2) do
    local choice = textTable[math.random(1,#textTable)]
    script.Parent:WaitForChild("ComputerGui").Game1.TextLabel.Text = choice
    table.remove(textTable, choice)
    choice = textTable[math.random(1,#textTable)]
end
```

I have looked into this but nothing has helped my situation. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The second argument in table.remove is the index of what you want to remove, not the thing you want to remove.

Comment: So what would I replace it with?

Comment: The index of what you want to remove.

Comment: `local index = math.random(1,#textTable); local choice = textTable[index]; table.remove(textTable, index)`

Comment: I tried that, I got another error. invalid argument #2 to 'random' (interval is empty)

Comment: Well, the `textTable becomes empty, so you have to break out of the loop when the table is empty`

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```lua
while wait(2) do
    if #textTable == 0 then
        break
    end
    local choice = math.random(1,#textTable)
    script.Parent:WaitForChild("ComputerGui").Game1.TextLabel.Text = textTable[choice]
    table.remove(textTable, choice)
    choice = math.random(1,#textTable)
end
```

edit: just read the comments, added if statement check

Comment: the condition `textTable == {}` will always be false. The equality operator on tables compares pointer addresses, and `{}` always creates a new table. If you want to check if a table is empty, you should use `if next(textTable) == nil then` or `if #textTable == 0 then`.

Comment: oh ok thanks sorry about that

Comment: It works! I just removed the second math.random line because it was giving me errors. If I didn't come here for this it would've taken me a lot longer to do this.

Comment: cool, I wasn't sure if that was important to your script or not so I just kept it. If it was helpful please mark it as correct as it helps other people know. <3